# Is it possible to Install KDE on arch linux on WiFi?

Tags: arch-linux

I have just finished installation of arch on my laptop. Wired ethernet connection was not possible here but I managed to complete the installation process using WiFi and wifi-menu command.
On launching the OS, I noticed wifi-menu doesn't work anymore and installing it from Pacman would require an internet connection.
So, can I use the live USB stick or some command to install a desktop environment on WiFi?

Comment: Did you try a usb tether from your phone and fix your [wifi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless) from there?

Comment: @bu5hman I did try following this reddit post(https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/2v8k8o/the_arch_iso_supports_android_usb_tethering/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=post_body) but when I ran the command an error came that said dhcpcd command not found. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use my phone's connection using USB tethring but it didn't work initially because of missing dhcpcd command.
So, I used a live USB to chroot into the system by
$mount /dev/sdx /mnt
$arch-chroot /mnt
After this, I fixed the broken packages and installed dhcpcd by
$pacman -Syy
$pacman -S dhcpcd
$exit
Then after rebooting into arch and turning on my phone's USB tethring, everything worked fine.
To test your connection, use
$ping -c 3 google.com